# Ways to serialize a class with Object field?

Tags: java, serialization

I've been using a class:

```
public class Change {
    Object affectedObj;  //takes an instance of any class
    String affectedFieldName;
    float shift;
    ...

    public void apply() {
        affectedObj.getClass().getField(affectedFieldName).setFloat(affectedObj, shift);
    }
}
```

which I now need to serialize. Since `Object` is not serializable, how can I make my class serializable?

One thing that came to my mind is to replace `Object` with generic `<T>` type:

```
public class Change<T> {
    T affectedObj;  //takes an instance of any class
    String affectedFieldName;
    float shift;
    ...

    public void apply() {
        affectedObj.getClass().getField(affectedFieldName).setFloat(affectedObj, shift);
    }
}
```

But I can't judge about the downsides of this approach. If it's a good way to go what are the pitfalls here regarding serialization?

PS

Thank you, guys, for your reply. They all were revealing and helpful to me.

Comment: If you don't need this field to be serialized at all, you could also mark it with the keyword "transient".

Comment: No, that's the point that I need it to make apply() method work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is not necessarily any problem. `Object` is not `Serializable`, but it's also *not not* `Serializable`. You *can* still serialize a class which declares `Object` fields, *provided* that at the moment of serialization the fields happen to be either null or they point to instances of `Serializable` objects. (Otherwise, serialization will fail with a `NotSerializableException`.)

If you really need `affectedObj` to be "any class", well then you do have a problem, because there are some things that cannot be serialized no matter how hard you try (open net connections, for example).

If you want to restrict `affectedObj` to `Serializable` objects, simply declare the field as type `Serializable`:

```
public class Change implements Serializable {
    Serializable affectedObj; // takes an instance of any Serializable class
    ...
}
```

It is not necessary to use generics for this. You can still use generics if you want it for other reasons, for example if you want users of the class to be able to set *and get* that field in a fully-typed way. It doesn't affect serialization however.

Comment: Thank you. This approach is more laconic. I like it better than mine.

Answer (score 1):

Making your class generic wont help you unless you restrict T to be Serializable by adding `Change<T extends Serializable>`, however it will restrict the types your class can accept.

Another option is to implement [Externalizable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Externalizable.html) but then you would need to implement both read() and write() and will have to serialize an unknown object anyway.

Is there any reason not to use a non java specific format such as json, thrift, msgpack or other?

Comment: There's no special reason except that I'm not familiar with them. But I'll take a look. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like a bad approach, but I would definitely upper-bind your generic parameter as such:

```
public class Change<T extends Serializable> {
    ...
}
```

This will ensure you can't parametrize your class with non-serializable types.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It was helpful and close very to David Rabinowitz's answer but his was a bit more comprehensive so I marked it to be the accepted answer.